# display none on desktop / mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm not sure what is wrong here and i'm drawing a blank.

I've 2 tables. One I want to display to desktop users and one to mobile users, 
So I was trying to set a display none here is my code.

```
.mobile{display: none;}
```

This was the css to side the mobile table on desktop

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
.desktop{display: none;}
.mobile{ display:block;}}
```

This was the code for hiding the desktop table on mobile.

and here was the html

```
<table class="desktop">
 <tr>
  <td><img src="images/aqu-landing_icon-win.png"></td>
  <td><img src="images/aqu-landing_icon-mac.png"></td>
  <td><img src="images/aqu-landing_icon-and.png"></td>
  <td><img src="images/aqu-landing_icon-ios.png"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Windows PC</td>
  <td>Apple PC</td>
  <td>Android Device</td>
  <td>iOS Device</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table class="mobile">
 <tr>
  <td><img src="images/aqu-landing_icon-and2.png"></td>
  <td><img src="images/aqu-landing_icon-ios2.png"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Android Device</td>
  <td>iOS Device</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Should this work as I have it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996925/display-none-show-on-the-mobile-but-not-on-the-desktop?rq=1

Comment: no, you have not set an upper width for you mobile and you have not set the opposite styles as a default

Comment: use max-width instead of min-width

Comment: implement the other guys answers, and you should be fine - set the max-width about 425 for bigger phones than a iPhone 4, and remember to have this is the header <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px)
```

Means: for devices with a screen and a **minimum** width of 320px. So that will affect all wider than 320px.

To address mobile phones, you should use the `max-width`

```
.mobile { display: none; }

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
   .desktop{ display: none; }
   .mobile{ display:block; }
}
```

Also make sure that the media query comes after the first line... otherwise it will override it.

Comment: Big mobile phones are abut 425 px wide in css terms - So you should maybe also go up to there

Answer (score 0):

Just change in your style,

```
min-width : 320px
```

into

```
max-width : 320px
```

It's working.